# How do I export a tornadofx application?

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I finished writing a little tornadofx app in IntelliJ CE and now want to export it as a single file which can be downloaded and launched by users. For now it would be sufficient to provide a single jar file. But it would be also great to know on how to export a self contained installer for OSX, Windows and Linux. Unfortunately I don't know how to do any of that. Can you help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [FxLauncher](https://github.com/edvin/fxlauncher) project, which is also from the creator of tornadoFX. FXLauncher allows you to easily distribute your javafx/tornadoFX application. The project provides a maven-plugin which allows you to generate a self containing javafx/tornadoFX application that you then publish to a web-server or common directory (e.g an internal app in your company network). After that you can generate native installers for Linux, OSX and Windows. The installer itself will only install a small app, which will know the location of your web-serve or directory. On startup it will download the latest deployed version of you application and run it. 
Additional links:

- [GitHub-project](https://github.com/edvin/fxlauncher)
- [Introduction screen cast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCP9wjRPQ14)
- [Customizing update ui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6PlFVUgntU)

Comment: Great answer @nimakro :) I just want to add that FXLauncher is actually using javapackager under the covers, which comes with the JDK. A TornadoFX application is in essence exactly the same as a normal JavaFX application when it comes to pacakge and deployment. The only difference is that you also need the tornadofx runtime jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want a single `jar` file, you can export it as a regular Java program (not the `JavaFX` option in IntelliJ). You do this by creating and building an artifact.

- Go to the *Project Structure* window, and from there select *Artifacts*
- Click the "+" icon to create a new artifact, and select *JAR > From modules with dependencies...*
- Select the main class and press *OK*

And that's it, the artifact has been set up, now, to generate `jar` file, just go to *Build > Build Artifacts* menu, and select the newly-made artifact, and the IntelliJ will generate the `jar` file in the "out" directory.

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it's what I've been using, and it works for me.