# I'm trying to distribute my TornadoFX desktop app in any way (export to a .jar executable or an installation), but I can't seem to figure out how

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, javafx, tornadofx

first time I ask a question but I'll try to be as clear as possible.

Basically, I built a simple TornadoFX desktop app in IntelliJ using Kotlin to be able to fill a database through an API. This is so that my client has a simple app and UI to easily fill this database without confusing API requests, etc.

Now, I've finished the entire application and want to "release" it. By this I mean that I want to somehow be able to send the application to my client so that they can test and eventually use it. To both me and the client, it doesn't really matter how it will be released. It could be an installation for the program, it could be a .exe or .jar, or something else I don't know about.
The point is, I want to finish it.

What I've tried so far is creating and building artifacts in IntelliJ, using "JAR" and "JavaFX application". The resulting .jar did not open properly and the JavaFX application build failed. I hoped this would work, since TornadoFX uses JavaFX, but alas.
After this not working, I tried to use FXLauncher to create installations for my app, but I will be honest and say that, with the tutorials that they provided, I still did not at all understand how to do it.
That is basically everything I've tried.

This is my project structure in IntelliJ:

[image: structure]

Nothing special, just a simple project with NcbAdminPcApp.kt containing the class implementing App and overriding the start method to start the application with (which is how you do that with TornadoFX in case this doesn't sounds familiar).

I don't believe I have specific code to show to make my case clearer, it's just a really simple application but releasing it has not worked so far.
I hope someone can help me! I'm willing to answer any questions and thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I export a tornadofx application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267553/how-do-i-export-a-tornadofx-application)

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: As you are using gradle, you might want to look at: the badass jlink plugin [git](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin), [doc](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/).  The function will be similar to the maven based JPackageScriptFX linked by mipa.  The links are for a modularized app version, if you want a non-modularized app version see the [badass-runtime-plugin](https://github.com/beryx/badass-runtime-plugin).

Comment: @Andrey actually no. I feel like FXLauncher is the best option, but I still have no idea how to use it and can't seem to find the information for me to get it... idk if I'm just too dumb to understand or just too inexperienced ahahaha

Comment: @pjs thanks for the comment. First question on here so, oops